# EmptyStackException when trying to implement Comparator

Tags: java

I'm new here and I have a problem.
I'm trying to implement a Comparator to compare two stacks by top.
The code looks like this

```
class Comp implements Comparator<Stack<Integer>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Stack<Integer> st1,Stack <Integer> st2) {
        return st1.peek()-st2.peek();
    }
}
```

I got `java.util.EmptyStackException` at `st1.peek()-st2.peek();` and I don't know why. Maybe you will help me with better implementation for my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Post the code which uses this comparator

Comment: looks like you are trying to sort an empty stack... post the minimal code

Comment: oh, i found the mistake. I thought that my stacks are not empty, but some of them were empty.Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

`Stack.peek` throws `EmptyStackException` when the stack is empty.
You need to check if the stack is empty before calling `peek` on it,
for example, if you want the empty stacks to come before non-empty ones:

```
@Override
public int compare(Stack<Integer> st1, Stack<Integer> st2) {
  if (st1.isEmpty() && st2.isEmpty()) {
     return 0;
  }
  if (st1.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (st2.isEmpty()) {
    return 1;
  }
  return st1.peek() - st2.peek();
}
```

Or if you want the empty stacks to come after the non-empty ones:

```
@Override
public int compare(Stack<Integer> st1, Stack<Integer> st2) {
  if (st1.isEmpty() && st2.isEmpty()) {
     return 0;
  }
  if (st1.isEmpty()) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (st2.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
  }
  return st1.peek() - st2.peek();
}
```

Comment: Both comparators should return 0 if both stacks are empty.